# Chicken Scheme: make-table unbound variable

Tags: chicken-scheme

I am trying to declare a hash table. Based on [this SRFI](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-90/srfi-90.html) I believe that the form `(define x (make-table))` ought to result in the correct behavior; however, I am getting the following error.

```
CHICKEN
(c) 2008-2017, The CHICKEN Team
(c) 2000-2007, Felix L. Winkelmann
Version 4.12.0 (rev 6ea24b6)
linux-unix-gnu-x86-64 [ 64bit manyargs dload ptables ]
compiled 2017-02-19 on yves.more-magic.net (Linux)

#;1> (make-table)

Error: unbound variable: make-table

        Call history:

        eval.scm:211: ##sys#get   
        eval.scm:218: values      
        eval.scm:255: ##sys#alias-global-hook     
        modules.scm:769: ##sys#qualified-symbol?          
        modules.scm:777: ##sys#active-eval-environment    
        modules.scm:777: g2354    
        modules.scm:784: mrename          
        modules.scm:762: ##sys#current-module     
        eval.scm:259: ##sys#symbol-has-toplevel-binding?     
        eval.scm:265: ##sys#symbol-has-toplevel-binding?     
        library.scm:1668: after   
        eval.scm:857: g1785       
        <eval>    (make-table)
        library.scm:4051: ##sys#get-call-chain    
        library.scm:3834: ##sys#make-vector       
        library.scm:1371: ##sys#allocate-vector         <--
```

In addition, I am getting similar errors for other functions. Is it possible I have installed the interpreter incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CHICKEN does not ship with SRFI 90, and as far as I can tell so far nobody has made an egg for it, either. An earlier and more commonly used hash table library, SRFI-69, is [part of core](https://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Unit%20srfi-69), though. It is also not available by default, you'll need to use it like so:

```
(use srfi-69)
```

In CHICKEN 5 (which I highly recommend you install, as it has many many improvements and is the currently supported major version), SRFI-69 is no longer part of core but can be installed [as an egg](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/5/srfi-69) via `chicken-install`. There, `use` no longer exists. Instead, after installing the egg you can import it like so:

```
(import srfi-69)
```

As an aside, SRFIs are "requests for implementation", and not every Scheme system implements every single SRFI. Sometimes because people object to the SRFI (some are controversial), sometimes because nobody has gotten around to it, sometimes because the SRFI is unimplementable/does make sense for a particular Scheme (for example, a C FFI makes no sense in a Scheme running on the JVM).

You'd have to check your Scheme's features to see if the SRFI you'd like to use is included. Note that for CHICKEN, many SRFIs are implemented outside of the core via eggs. CHICKEN core includes only a handful of SRFIs, like 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 23, 30, 39, 55, 69. In CHICKEN 5, the SRFIs 1, 13, 14 and 69 have been taken out of core as they can be implemented externally quite easily. Check the [list of eggs](https://eggs.call-cc.org) for more SRFI implementations.

Edit: I forgot, there's a [wiki page](https://wiki.call-cc.org/supported-standards) that strives to list all supported SRFIs exhaustively. It hasn't been updated for CHICKEN 5 yet, but the list should eventually be the same, as more and more eggs get ported from CHICKEN 4 to 5 (and even become longer, given that CHICKEN 5 sees much new development).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got version 5 setup. 

I am having trouble installing srfi-69 (or any other egg) with `chicken-install` I get an error `Error: extension or version not found: "srfi-69"`. Is this a problem with not having the correct egg repository? I have tried with the sudo and verbose flag but the output is the same.

Comment: Can you paste the full output of `chicken-install -verbose srfi-69`?

Comment: Absolutely 

`srfi-69 not cached

Error: extension or version not found: "srfi-69"`

Comment: It looks like you installed CHICKEN with a PREFIX that is wrong (or you haven't installed CHICKEN yet?).  Please try `chicken-install -u`, see if that gives an error.

Comment: I think you are correct that I gave the wrong prefix when installing Chicken! When I run `chicken-install -u` I get the error `loading import libraries ...
generating database ...

Error: (open-output-file) cannot open file - No such file or directory: "/opt/chicken/lib/chicken/9/modules.db"`

What was I suppose to set the PREFIX var to? I reread the install guide and couldn't figure it out! Is there a way to change this without reinstalling chicken?

Comment: Okay thanks for your help. I cleaned out the installation and installed it *without* defining a perfix and that worked! As a point of interest: I have to install eggs with root privilege because because the default install directory is `/usr/local`. Is this what people do or should I redefine the PREFIX to somewhere I own?

Comment: Good to hear you at least found out the cause.  Certainly you can set `$PREFIX` to whatever you want (can be `/opt/chicken` or `~/chicken`, whichever you prefer). However, when you invoke `make` for the first time, it will write a `chicken-config.h` which contains these path settings (using the default `PREFIX` if you did not supply one).  If later you call `make` again with a different `PREFIX`, it will not regenerate `chicken-config.h`, causing a mismatch between where it installs CHICKEN versus where it looks for data and config files; if you set `PREFIX`, use he same on every `make` call.